# imagebutton above a camera preview

Tags: android, android-camera, android-imagebutton

i want to put an imagebutton on top of camera preview.
it's simple unless you want to move the button.

the layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/my_linear_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
   <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
    />
   <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

If i put the button at the bottom of the screen it works fine. But if i put the button at the center, for exemple, and move it towards the bottom, it disappears because the linearLayout is not fullscreen.

what it's the best way to do what i want? thank's

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to use a `FrameLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/my_linear_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: i have the same problem with this code. when i move towards the bottom the imagebutton disappears